# v-autocomplete does not show drop down if the search term does not match

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a search box using v-autocomplete where the user can search based on institution name or city. The drop down will display only the institution names. When a user search for by city, I see that v-autocomplete has the data (on looking from debugger) but the drop down is not displayed for user to pick an institution. When a user search by institution name, it displays the drop down correctly.

I suspect v-autocomplete component match the search term with the data and display the drop down only if there is a match. Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if it takes more than two years to have a response but I was stucked at this same point and I think that an answer can help other people searching for a solution!

It is enought to add the attribute `no-filter` to the tag:

```
<v-autocomplete
  color="white"
  item-text="value"
  item-value="id"
  no-filter
  ...
```

Hope it may be helpfull.